# Checkmark is not changing

Tags: swift, uitableview

My app has two tableViews. when I click the first tableview cell it shows another tableview with list of items. I placed checkmark to select particular item.I am sending the array named "arraytofill" data through segue from first viewController.

I want to place the checkmark that is equal to the selected item in secondviewcontroller to detailtextlabel in first viewController

I done a concept if `detailtextlabel == indexpath.row`

place checkmark

After when I select a nextitem the checkmark is placing but the first checkmark is not removing it stays I don't know how to remove that.

Pls help me to do that

Thanks in advance

```
import UIKit

protocol DataSentDelagate {

    func userDidEnterData(data: String)  

}

class TableViewController2: UITableViewController {

    var arraytofill = [String]()

    var dk:String = ""
    var delegate: DataSentDelagate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
          }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arraytofill.count

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = arraytofill[indexPath.row]

        if indexPath.row == UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "store"){

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

        }else if dk == arraytofill[indexPath.row]{

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        return cell
    }    

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.row, forKey: "store")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
       let selectedcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let data = selectedcell.textLabel?.text;    

       if delegate != nil {
            delegate?.userDidEnterData(data: data!)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set dk ? Where ? Did you test (breakpoint) at cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

Comment: dk is getting value from firstviewController through segue. Its getting detaillabeltext value